# Glide Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule

Tags: android, android-glide, image-loading

I was using the GlideLibrary to load a list of images to show it on the mobile UI.I'm getting the following error:

`Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored`.

I have seend the question been asked in stack, but no proper solution is provided. Please suggest any good way to solve this issue.

Please find the sample code :

`Glide.with(getContext( )).load(ImageUri).into(ProductsImageView)`

Gradle File:

`implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'`

`annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'`

Comment: Did you try something like clean project, rebuild, invalidate cashes?

Comment: @adnandann - Rebuild Project is done from my end.! The warning use to show even when I do nothing.

Comment: Looks like this could be an open known issue: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/4476