# Glide 4.12.0 Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage, android-glide, image-loading

I was using Glide to display image from firebase storage but I am getting this error:

*W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored*

I have tried to find the solutions from [Glide Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65970031/glide-failed-to-find-generatedappglidemodule) and [Android Glide "Cannot Resolve Method 'with' in GlideApp"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022318/android-glide-cannot-resolve-method-with-in-glideapp) but both of them did not work.

Below are my sample code in recycler view adapter:

*Glide.with(context).load(imageurl).into(viewHolder.getImageview());*

and I am using the latest version of Glide:

*implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'*

Clean, rebuild project and invalidate/restart did not work for me. I appreciate if anyone could suggest solution to solve this issue. Thank you.

My codes in build.gradle (project):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

My codes in build.gradle (module):

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
```

My codes in proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule {
  <init>(...);
}
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
   **[] $VALUES;
   public *;
}
-keep class
 com.bumptech.glide.load.data.ParcelFileDescriptorRewinder$InternalRewinder {
   *** rewind();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [documentation](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), you must:

1. paste in your Gradle file

   repositories {
   google()
   mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
   implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
   annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
   }
2. Proguard - Depending on your ProGuard (DexGuard) config and usage, you may need to include the following lines in your proguard.cfg

   ```
    -keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
    -keep class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule {
     <init>(...);
    }
    -keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
      **[] $VALUES;
      public *;
    }
    -keep class 
    com.bumptech.glide.load.data.ParcelFileDescriptorRewinder$InternalRewinder {
      *** rewind();
     }

    # for DexGuard only
    -keepresourcexmlelements manifest/application/meta-data@value=GlideModule
   ```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution but it did not fix my problem. The error still exists after I adding these codes. I have added my codes (build.gradle and proguard-rules.pro) in my post above. Thank you.